# New user can't login from FTP in ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: login, adduser, proftpd

I have install a new ubuntu server 14.04 instance on our server and creating a user for FTP access.but the the user can log in via terminal on the server but can't login via FTP.I am using proftpd for FTP server.Can anyone help me out from this situation?

Comment: You mean using FTP client like Filezilla? what error message you get when you try to connect?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am using filezilla and the error showing that Password is incorrect.but I checked that password is correct. Using the same password the user can login via terminal on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

On server machine:

```
sudo service proftpd restart
```

then

```
netstat -tpan | grep 21
```

make sure proftp is open on the server machine on 0.0.0.0 or public ip

Use

```
nmap my.server.ip.num
```

from the client machine to make sure the port is open (21).